# How does MAX_VALUE+1 & MIN_VALUE-1 works with all the data types of java?

Tags: java

```
public class Min_Max{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //byte max & min
        // byte maxByte=Byte.MAX_VALUE;
        // byte maxByte_add1=Byte.MAX_VALUE+1;//Cannot convert from int to byte
        // byte minByte=Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        // byte minByte_sub1=Byte.MIN_VALUE-1;//Cannot convert from int to byte
        // //short max & min
        // short maxShort=Short.MAX_VALUE;
        // short maxShort_add1=Short.MAX_VALUE+1;//Cannot convert from int to short
        // short minShort=Short.MIN_VALUE;
        // short minShort_sub1=Short.MIN_VALUE-1;//Cannot convert from int to short
        //integer max & min
        int maxInt=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Integer max value :"+maxInt);
        int maxInt_add1=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
        System.out.println("Max+1 :"+maxInt_add1);
        int minInt=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Integer min value :"+minInt);
        int minInt_sub1=Integer.MIN_VALUE-1;
        System.out.println("Min-1 :"+minInt_sub1);
        //float max & min
        float maxFloat=Float.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Float max value :"+maxFloat);
        float maxFloat_add1=Float.MAX_VALUE+1;
        System.out.println("Max+1 :"+maxFloat_add1);
        float minFloat=Float.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Float min value :"+minFloat);
        float minFloat_sub1=Float.MIN_VALUE-1;
        System.out.println("Min-1 :"+minFloat_sub1);
        //double max & min
        double maxDouble=Double.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Double Max value :"+maxDouble);
        double maxDouble_add1=Double.MAX_VALUE+1;
        System.out.println("Max+1 :"+maxDouble_add1);
        double minDouble=Double.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Double Min value :"+minDouble);
        double minDouble_sub1=Double.MIN_VALUE-1;
        System.out.println("Min-1 :"+minDouble_sub1);
    }
}
```

[![OUTPUT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF1ha.png)
For `byte` & `short`=>Cannot convert from int to byte or short.
`int`=>Max value=min value-1 and Min value=Max value+1
`float` & `double`=>Max value=Max value+1 and no order for min values.

Can anyone explain how do these data types work for min-1 & max+1 values and why act in different ways?

Comment: What do you mean by "no order for min values"? I got -1.0 as the Min-1 of float and double.

Comment: Actually, I cannot understand why the different data types act in different ways.

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE+1? Float.MIN_VALUE-1? Hm....What a "wonderful" question !

Answer (score 1):

The lines that don't compile don't compile because `+` and `-` are two of those operators that cause their operands to undergo [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). The rules are:

> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

So if none of the operands are `double`, `float` or `long`, then both operands are converted to `int`, as is the case with your code. And `int` can't be implciitly converted to `byte` or `short`.

The max value of `int` is equal to the min value of `int` minus one because that's how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works. The binary representation of the max value is:

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Whereas the binary representation of the min value is:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

You can now see how adding one to the max value gives you the min value, and subtracting one from the min value gives you the max value.

For `float` and `double`, the reason for max value = max value + 1 is basically that they are not precise enough to represent the value of max value + 1. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) The result is rounded to the nearest representable value, which just so happens to be the max value. A more precise description is found in the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If the magnitude of the sum is too large to represent, we say the operation overflows; the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign.
>
> Otherwise, **the sum is rounded to the nearest value** in the chosen value set using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode. The Java programming language requires support of gradual underflow as defined by IEEE 754 (§4.2.4).

For why min value - 1 is -1.0, well, have a look at what the min value actually is. For `float`, It is `1.4E-45`, a *positive* number that is very close to 0. Well what happens when you subtract 1 from a number that is slightly more than 0? You get approximately -1! Again, `float` and `double` can't represent this nearly-negative-one number precisely, so it shows -1.0.

You might have misunderstood `Float.MIN_VALUE` as the most negative value that `Float` can have, but that's not what it is about. The most negative value that `Float` can have is `-Float.MAX_VALUE`, or `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, depending on whether you count infinity as a "number" or not.